# Grails Ajax Timer

Tags: ajax, grails, migration

I am developping a migration program, which transfers the data from sybase to postgresql in grails. In the backend, a grails migration service is running in a dedicated thread. In the frontend, I want to display how many data and how much time the grails service takes.
In this moment, I can only manually refresh the gsp page so that the current time can number of data can be displayed on the gsp page. However, a good idea is to refresh the gsp page automatically via ajax timer. I try to use the setInterval or setTimeOut on HTML, but it somehow doesn't work at all.
The following is my grails controller and corresponding view

```
def migrateSchuldner() {
    def isRunning = personMigrationThreadService.isRunning() // boolean is the Service is running
    def results = MigrationRun.findAllByEndDateIsNull()
    def threadInfo
    if (results.empty) {
        def runCounter = personMigrationService.lastRun()
        threadInfo = MigrationRun.findByCounter(runCounter) // threadInfo contains the Date and processedData and ErrorData
    }
    else {
        threadInfo = results.get(0)
    }
    render view: 'migrateSchuldner', model: [threadInfo: threadInfo, isRunning: isRunning]
}
```

The corresponding view is:

```
<%@ page import="de.rvgmbh.nemesis.domain.security.Role" %>
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_MIGRATION">
<g:applyLayout name="mainSecured" params="[currentTopNavigationIndex: 'migration',  currentLeftNavigationIndex: 3]">
    <head>
        <title>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.headline.show')}  
    </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="span-20 rightBorder">
        <h3>${message(code: "page.migration.migrate.schuldnerData.headline.show")}</h3>
    </div>

    <fieldset id="migration-form">
        <table>
            <tr><td style="background-color: transparent">
                <g:if test="${isRunning}">
                    <legend>
                        ${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.migrationInProgress')}
                    </legend>
                </g:if>
                <g:else>
                    <g:form action="migrateSchuldnerButtonClick" method="post" useToken="true">
                        ${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.legend.text')}
                        <input type="submit"
                               value= ${message(code: "page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.submit.text")}>
                    </g:form>
                </g:else>
                <g:if test="${threadInfo}">
                    <g:if test="${!isRunning}">
                        <legend>
                            ${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.lastResult')}
                        </legend>
                    </g:if>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.currentTime')}:</label>
                            <p>${threadInfo.currentRuntime}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.processedPersons')}:</label>

                            <p>${threadInfo.processedPersons}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.personErrors')}:</label>

                            <p>${threadInfo.personErrors}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.processedPersonData')}:</label>

                            <p>${threadInfo.processedPersonData}</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>${message(code: 'page.migration.migrate.SchuldnerData.dataErrors')}:</label>

                            <p>${threadInfo.dataErrors}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </g:if>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    </body>
</g:applyLayout>
```

The thing is the variable currentRuntime, processedPersons... are always updating inside the thread. I have to refresh the gsp view to get the current time and processedPersons.
Does anyone have a idea which Ajax timer I should use to achieve the goal

Comment: Can you show your Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

1)  Move the whole `<fieldset id="migration-form">` to a separate action, say, `progress` with `progress.gsp`. Enclose the action [include](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) into a div with id:

```
def progress = {
  [threadInfo: threadInfo]
}
```

in main page:

```
<div id="migration_progress">
  <g:include action="progress" model="[threadInfo: threadInfo]">
</div>
```

2) Use [remoteFunction](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) to update `migration_progress` div by timer like:

```
onsomething="${remoteFunction(action: 'progress', update: 'migration_progress')"
```